# button modal in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

i want to implement a modal in angularjs,by pressing button so i add a button and wrote code for modal and also html code for the modal but it doesnot showing any modal

myhtml code is posted below:

```
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title"> Im a modal!</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
   </script>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!      </button>
      </div>

       </body>
```

this is my angular code where ng-animate,ui-bootstrap and added these script files in html head.

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {
   $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
    $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
   animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
   templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    });
    };
   });


  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

 $scope.ok = function () {
  $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
   $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   };
  });
```

Comment: @Yvette,when i click on the button it has to show the model but the code doesnot works is there any mistake in code

Comment: @MsYvette,i want to implement a modal in angularjs,by pressing button so i add a button and wrote code for modal and also html code for the modal but it doesnot showing any modal

Comment: Tell us if you see any error in the console. If you don't have any, post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

The html code is your whole html code ?
If yes, you forget to include ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" on body or parent div.

(and try to indent your code, it will be more clear and easier ;) :) )

Answer (score -1):

first of all you need to upgrade your bootstrap plugin file.
after that

you need to write code like this

add button

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
 data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
 <i class="fa fa-filter"></i> open modal </button>
```

and code for modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">              
                <h4 class="modal-title">ABC</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">           
               ABC

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-ng-click="ABC()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-ng-click="SAVE()" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```